# Unable to loop through Dataframe rows: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, sentiment-analysis

I'm not entirely sure why I am getting this error as I have a *very* simple dataframe that I am currently working with. Here is a sample of the dataframe (the date column is the index):

| date | News |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | This is a news headline. This is a news summary. |
| 2021-02-02 | This is another headline. This is another summary |

So basically, all I am trying to do is loop through the dataframe one row at a time and pull the News item, use the Sentiment Intensity Analyzer on it and store the compound value into a separate list (which I am appending to an empty list). However, when I run the loop, it gives me this error:

> Length of values (5085) does not match the length of index (2675)

Here is a sample of the code that I have so far:

```py
      sia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
      news_sentiment_list = []  
      
      for i in range (0, (df_news.shape[0]-1)):
        n = df_news.iloc[i][0]
        news_sentiment_list.append(sia.polarity_scores(n)['compound'])
    
      df['News Sentiment'] = news_sentiment_list
```

I've tried the loop statement a number of different ways using the FOR loop, and I always return that error. I am honestly lost at this point =(

edit: The shape of the dataframe is: (5087, 1)

Answer (score 1):

The target dataframe is `df` whereas you loop on `df_news`, the indexes are probably not the same. You might need to merge the dataframes before doing so.

Moreover, there is an easier approach to your problem that would avoid having to loop on it. Assuming your dataframe `df_news` holds the column `News` (as shown on your table), you can add a column to this dataframe simply by doing:

```py
sia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
df_news['News Sentiment'] = df_news['News'].apply(lambda x: sia.polarity_scores(x)['compound'])
```

A general rule when using `pandas` is to avoid as much as possible using `for-loops`, except when you have a very specific edge case panda's built-in methods will be sufficient.

Comment: Good catch arhr! I must be looking at the code too much as I didn't even catch that. Thank you for the second pair of eyes =)